# ValueError: operation parameter must be str

Tags: python, sqlite3

Estoy tratando de borrar un registro con el dato contenido en una variable fuera de la instrucción que va en `cursor.execute()` pero me da un error:

> ValueError: operation parameter must be str

```
import sqlite3
conexion = sqlite3.connect("BaseEjemplo.db")
cursor = conexion.cursor()

variable = 125

consulta = ("DELETE FROM TablaEjemplo WHERE Codigo=?",(variable))

cursor.execute(consulta)

conexion.commit()
conexion.close()
```

Comment: cursor.execute("DELETE FROM TablaEjemplo WHERE Codigo=?",(variable))

Answer (score 0):

Tienes dos errores:

- Le pasas a `cursor.execute` una tupla como primer argumento de la forma `(operación, parámetros)` cuando o que espera es la cadena con la operación, la cadena con la query. Por eso salta la excepción, porque espera una cadena con la query como primer argumento y recibe una tupla.
- El segundo argumento de `execute` son los parámetros y espera que sean un iterable. No pasas una tupla con los parámetros:

  ```
  (variable)
  ```

  es lo mismo que:

  ```
  variable
  ```

  los paréntesis aquí son solo eso, paréntesis, afectan al orden de evaluación de la expresión pero no son parte del literal de una tupla. Para que lo sean debes añadir una coma:

  ```
  (variable,)
           ^
           ^
  ```

  Como le pasas un entero, que no es iterable obtendrás un error del tipo:

  > ValueError: parameters are of unsupported type

---

Si quieres usar una tupla `(operación, parámetros)`, debes desempaquetarla al llamar a `execute`:

```
consulta = ("DELETE FROM TablaEjemplo WHERE Codigo=?", (variable,))
cursor.execute(*consulta)
```

O simplemente:

```
variable = 125
consulta = "DELETE FROM TablaEjemplo WHERE Codigo=?"

cursor.execute(consulta, (variable,))
```

Comment: hola amigo gracias por la explicacion se entendio perfecto saves que hice como me dijiste pero algo mas mal ahi por que ahora modifique el codigo como vos me dijiste y se pudooo funcionoo estobe 12 horas trtando de resolver ese problema muchas graciass esaaaaaa

Comment: ultima consulta : en cursor.execute(*consulta) el * que funcion cumple?

Comment: Desempaqueta la tupla, es decir `cursor.execute(*(foo, bar))` equivale a `cursor.execute(foo, bar)` que es lo que espera el método.